# how to download data behind core web vital report in google search console via api?

Tags: python, google-search-console, core-web-vitals

I am looking for a way to download the data behind core web vital reports in google search console. is there any api for this?
so far the only thing I find is the page speed api which is providing the current analysis for given url.
What I need is the counts and distribution per day which is exactly what is shown in this report:
[image]

There is a link to download when I navigate into the report, but I am looking for a python api kind of thing to programmatically download this data.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GSC API currently does not support these new reports.

The Core Web Vitals data comes from the [CrUX report](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report) data which does have [an API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/api/reference). So you can get similar data via that. I think the PSI API also includes data from CrUX if available. It would probably take some work to get the data in the structure you want it.

Comment: Thank you Tony for the response, however, I don't see a clean approach to getting the data. seems like the api for CrUX is just giving sort of instructions on how to draw the histograms! not statistics distributed by day! Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: The GSC report is also not a true day to day report. Each day shows the average over the previous 28 days, as per the CrUX api. So you could get the same sort of data if you use the API every day. The other complexity is that GSC has data for all the urls where data exists, and they do their own grouping. I don't think there is an easy way to do that via the API.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I guess I better off using day to day accumulation until google provides something that makes more sense!